# Sublime Text 3: XDebug does not stop in breakpoints anymore

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext, xdebug, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04

It used to work after following this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/

Now, it is not working if I put a break point. However, as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021964/xdebug-wont-stop-at-breakpoint/10567626#10567626), **it does work if** I add the following line of code:

```
xdebug_break();
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I think it stopped working after I hibernated the system without stopping the XDebug session. I have rebooted the system. What could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has started to work after I have added the zend_extension line to my xdebug.ini. It is the whole code of the file:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

Not sure why it was working without that line before. Probably it is because of the following:

My XDebug has the following configuration:

> xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1

However Apache2 says:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive
>   globally to suppress this message

Lastly, to find where my xdebug.so is I typed:

```
cd /usr/lib/php5/
find . -name \*xdebug\*
```

Comment: I have `xdebug.so` in the xdebug.ini and still Sublime Text breakpoints are not working

Answer (score 0):

Addition @chelders answer: the line `extension = xdebug.so` may also not exist, otherwise it will not work either.